# Chrome Extension - executeScript not in active tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying a simple Chrome Extension example which should enable me change the background color of any open youtube tabs to red. What I've noticed is that the background of the page is only turned red if I'm on the actual page i.e. it is the active tab.

**Code:**

```
function getYouTubeTabs() {
    queryInfo = {
        'url': '*://www.youtube.com/*'
    };

    chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function (result) {
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {    
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(result[i].id, {
                code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This is the code I have, I might be missing something. Not sure if executeScript could be used on 'non-active' tabs. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "First menu item",
  "description": "Testing Context Menus",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus", "tabs", "activeTab"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "myicon.png",
    "128": "myicon2.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like a permissions issue. Please, post the manifest as well.

Comment: Just posted the manifest. Note that in the "background" section I tried adding "persistent": false but then I was not able to run the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **[activeTab](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html)** permission, allows you to ***[call tabs.executeScript or tabs.insertCSS on that tab](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html#what-activeTab-allows)***.

On the contrary, in order to be able to **[programmatically inject](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)** code into an non-active tab, besides the `tabs` permission, *your extension must have **[cross-origin permissions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html#requesting-permission)** for the page*.

So, you need to modify your manifest's `permissions` section like this:

```
"permissions": [
    ...
    "*://www.youtube.com/*"
],
```

---

Adding `"persistent": false` in the `background` section should work fine as well (and is the **[preferred way](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)**).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I must have read that somewhere just forgot about it.

Comment: Regarding the non-persistent background page (a.k.a. event page): Keep in mind that a context-menu's callback needs "special" registering for event pages (according to **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#property-createProperties-checked)**).